# How to make two separate 'tabular' environments have the same width?

Tags: tables

The widths of the two tabular environments can be different even though the sums of the individual cell widths are 5 cm in both cases. How to fix this?

For example, these two tables do not have the same width:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.025cm}
    \newcolumntype{B}{ >{\arraybackslash} m{2.500cm}}
    \begin{tabular}{|B|B|} \hline
    a & b  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.025cm}
    \newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.250cm}}
    \begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|} \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is no clearer than your previous question. As requested there please make a complete small document (presumably containing two tabular) that shows the issue that you are having. Why do you need to know the cell border (and what do you mean by border here?) do you mean the width of the white space (`\tabcolsep`) or teh width of a vertical rule (`\arrayrulewidth`) or something else?

Comment: Kevin: [this question and its answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) give guidelines for writing a good “minimal working example”, as @DavidCarlisle is saying.  Giving such an example will make it much easier for answerers to help you.

Comment: @David I added a MWE.

Comment: You're forgetting the padding inside the cells, for example the a cell needs and extra `2\tabcolsep` and the width of the rule (see the drawing), this seems to work: `\newcolumntype{B}{ >{\arraybackslash} 
      m{\dimexpr2.500cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}}`

Comment: @daleif That is still not working. The upper table is still smaller.

Comment: Please show the code of that, here it matches exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations appear to be ignoring (a) the amount of "whitespace padding" that's inserted to the left and right of each cell and (b) the widths of the vertical lines. In a `tabular` environment, the amount of whitespace padding is set by the parameter `\tabcolsep`; in many (most?) document classes, the default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`. The width of each line is set by `\arrayrulewidth`; its default value is generally `0.4pt`.

What you seem to have in mind is, implicitly, the special case where `\tabcolsep` is set to `0pt` or, equivalently, `0mm`, `0cm`, etc. Say, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "m" column type and "\newcolumntype" macro

    \setlength\tabcolsep{0mm}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.25mm}
    \newcolumntype{B}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{25.25mm}}
    \newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{12.5mm}}

\begin{document}
\centering

    \begin{tabular}{|B|B|} \hline
    u & v  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|} \hline
    u & v & w & x \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Observe that the first `tabular` features 2 cells (each 25.25mm wide) and 3 vertical lines (each 0.25mm wide). The second `tabular` features 4 cells (each 12.5mm wide) and 5 vertical lines (each 0.25mm wide). The *total width* of the first `tabular` environment is `2*25.25mm+3*0.25mm=51.25mm`, and the total width of the second `tabular` environment is `4*12.5mm+5*0.25mm=51.25mm`. I.e., the overall widths are exactly the same now.

Of course, setting the value of `\tabcolsep` to zero may not be acceptable to you -- in which case you'll have to adjust the column widths suitably to take into account the non-zero value of `\tabcolsep`.

Answer (score 1):

As your are using `tabularx` package you can use the `tabularx` environement
which allow to "stretch" tables.

You can define new columns type as following:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{B}{ >{\arraybackslash}X}
```

Note the `X` which is only available in `tabularx` environement.

> The column(s) specified with the `X` specifier will be stretched to make the table as wide as specified, greatly simplifying the creation of tables.

Then you can use it with `tabularx` environment by specifying the desired width of the table:

```
\begin{center}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.025cm}
    \begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|B|B|} \hline
    a & b  \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.025cm}
    \begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|C|C|C|C|} \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```

You can read more about Tables and `tabularx` on [LaTeX/Tables - Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabularx_package).

Comment: You may want to add a sentence or two to explain how the OP may deduce the *usable* width of the `B` and `C` cells. E.g., the usable width of each `B` cell is given by `(5cm-4*\tabcolsep- 3*\arrayrulewidth)/2`.